# Laravel migration cancel column as nullable

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, non-nullable

I created a migration with `name` column making `nullable`. How can I change `name` as not `nullable`? My previous migration code is given below:

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->string('name', 50)->nullable();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->nullable(false)->change();
});
```